# Towers of Hanoi with Classes

Tags: c++, class, towers-of-hanoi

I keep getting the Error C2228 left of '.topDisk' must have class/struct/union and I have no idea what it means, or even how to fix it, even after some research. Is it possible for someone to explain what the error is and how to fix it? I think I've provided you with all the code you need.

HanoiPegClass.cpp File

```
//A function moving one disk from one peg to another
void moveDisk(Peg& beginning, Peg& destination)
{
    assert(beginning.getNumDisks() > 0);
    if (destination.getNumDisks() > 0)
    {
        //Where the error is
        assert(beginning.getNumDisks.topDisk() < destination.getNumDisks.topDisk());
    }

    destination.addDisk(beginning.topDisk());
    beginning.removeDisk();
}
```

Peg.cpp File

```
//Function to return the disk count (amount of discs on each peg)
unsigned int Peg::getNumDisks() 
{
    return diskStack.size();
}

//Function to return the value of the top disk
int Peg::topDisk()
{
    return diskStack.back();    
}
```

Peg.h File

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Peg
{

private:
    vector<int> diskStack;
    string pegName;
    void setName(string name);
public:
    Peg(string name, int totalDisks);
    unsigned int getNumDisks();
    void printDisks();
    string getName();
    int topDisk();
    void addDisk(int totalDisks);
    int removeDisk();
    ~Peg();
};
```

Comment: The error is confusing because you forgot () on getNumDisks:
beginning.getNumDisks().topDisk() is still wrong but at least it'll tell you you can't call a function on an integer

Comment: Please make the example complete by just showing the real `Peg.h` file instead of paraphrasing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getNumDisks` is a function which returns an unsigned integer, so you cannot use a `.` on it. You can use the `.` operator on a `structure` or `class` or `union` only. 
So change

```
assert(beginning.getNumDisks.topDisk() < destination.getNumDisks.topDisk());
```

to

```
assert(beginning.topDisk() < destination.topDisk());
```

Comment: @G.Egelstad That's because the `assert` is triggered, so your logic contains an error.

Comment: @P.W That fixed it! And thanks for the simple explanation too.